# Simple way to show a bitmap next to a menu item in a CMenu with correct transparency

Tags: c#, winapi, bitmap, cmenu

First off, I'm not a C++ developer, I program mainly in C#. I am trying to use the ContextMenu (yes I'm aware of ContextMenuStrip) class in .NET which is a wrapper around CMenu in my application.

**How do I display an image next to a menu item that has proper transparency?**

What I've done so far is call [SetMenuItemBitmaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on my menu item, here is the attached result:

[image]

As you can see there is a white background on the menu item. This is just so frustratingly close to what I want. How can I get the transparency issues to go away? I've attached the exact image I used below on this menu item:

[image]

I know that SetMenuItemBitmaps is not meant for colored images.

> *The selected and clear bitmaps should be monochrome. The system uses
>   the Boolean AND operator to combine bitmaps with the menu so that the
>   white part becomes transparent and the black part becomes the
>   menu-item color. If you use color bitmaps, the results may be
>   undesirable.*

So what is the proper (hopefully simple) way of doing this?

**EDIT**

Another thing I tried was calling SetMenuItemInfo, but I keep getting error 87 (invalid parameter).

This is what the MENUITEMINFO structure looks like before I call SetMenuItemInfo:

[image]

And the values for the parameters I call on SetMenuItemInfo are:

**hMenu**       - The handle to the ContextMenu?

**uItem**       - 0 (the first item index?)

**fByPosition** - true

**lpmii**       - (the structure contents above)

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the structure that I can see, so maybe check that `hMenu` is valid? Maybe test by calling `GetMenuItemInfo()` to get something simple (`fState` for example).

Comment: @JonathanPotter Well I was able to get SetMenuItemInfo to work, thanks for the direction. The only problem is that it looks the exact same as the above (pixelated with white background).

Comment: Is your bitmap 32bpp with pre-multiplied alpha?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I followed this tutorial for creating a pre-multiplied alpha picture in GIMP: http://kevin.c.krinke.ca/2012/04/24/creating-images-with-pre-multiplied-alpha-using-gimp/ using the png I attached in my post, so yes, I believe so.

Comment: How are you getting that PNG into an HBITMAP?

Comment: @JonathanPotter In managed code I call GetHbitmap: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4.aspx

Comment: It seems like `GetHbitmap` loses the alpha channel - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275738/convert-hbitmap-to-bitmap-preserving-alpha-channel

Comment: @JonathanPotter Hey Jonathan, you've been a great help. I posted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322926/loading-image-onto-menuitem-is-losing-transparency-on-pre-multiplied-alpha-image) outlining the problem I'm currently facing. If you get a chance to look, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the menu item, simply set the `MIIM_BITMAP` flag and pass the `HBITMAP` in the `hbmpItem` member of the `MENUITEMINFO` structure. If your bitmap is 32bpp with pre-multiplied alpha then it will be displayed correctly.

Comment: Sorry to do this to you, but can you provide me an example of a proper call to SetMenuItemInfo which does what you've said? I actually attempted what you've described as my first attempt but could not get it to work.

Comment: `mi.fMask |= MIIM_BITMAP; mi.hbmpItem = hbmp;`

Comment: Yeah I figured that part, I just am not actually creating the menu in C++. It is a C# application so I have to pinvoke to do this. I'm not 100% sure how I would call SetMenuItemInfo and also populate the MENUITEMINFO structure. I consistently get error 87 (invalid parameter).

Comment: Maybe post some code (as another question, probably). And you should tag as C# if you're using C#.

Comment: I've made an edit, if you could take a look I'd greatly appreciate it.