# Loading image onto MenuItem is losing transparency on pre-multiplied alpha image

Tags: c#, winapi, contextmenu, alpha, gimp

I am really in need of some help here. I am trying to load an image which I believe to be 32bpp with pre-multiplied alpha onto a [MenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.aspx) ([I followed this guide to make the image in GIMP](http://kevin.c.krinke.ca/2012/04/24/creating-images-with-pre-multiplied-alpha-using-gimp/)). I am aware of the ContextMenuStrip class and do not want to use it.

The following is the code I am using to set the image onto the MenuItem:

```
// apis
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetMenuItemInfo(IntPtr hMenu, uint uItem, bool fByPosition,
                                   [In] ref MENUITEMINFO lpmii);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr LoadImage(IntPtr hinst, string lpszName, uint uType,
                               int cxDesired, int cyDesired, uint fuLoad);

// structures
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MENUITEMINFO
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public uint fMask;
    public uint fType;
    public uint fState;
    public uint wID;
    public IntPtr hSubMenu;
    public IntPtr hbmpChecked;
    public IntPtr hbmpUnchecked;
    public IntPtr dwItemData;
    public string dwTypeData;
    public uint cch;
    public IntPtr hbmpItem;
}

// constants
private const uint LR_LOADFROMFILE = 0x10u;
private const uint IMAGE_BITMAP = 0x0u;
private const uint MIIM_BITMAP = 0x80u;

// points the to the image below in the preview of GIMP
private const string IMAGE_PATH = @"C:\Test\Images\premultalpha.bmp";

// methods
private void SetMenuItemImage()
{

    // get the hbitmap for the image
    // i am assuming that the alpha channel is preservered on this call
    IntPtr hbitmap = LoadImage(IntPtr.Zero, IMAGE_PATH, 
                               IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

    // create the menuiteminfo structure
    MENUITEMINFO mii = new MENUITEMINFO();

    mii.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MENUITEMINFO));

    // retrieves or sets the hbmpItem member
    mii.fMask = MIIM_BITMAP;

    // handle to the bitmap displayed
    mii.hbmpItem = hbitmap;

    // returns true
    SetMenuItemInfo(this.ContextMenu1.Handle, 0, true, ref mii);
}
```

This is the result of the code using my image:

[image: Result of code]

The obvious problem here being that there is no transparency, instead there is a black background.

This is what the image looks like in GIMP after following the guide to make pre-multiplied alpha channel **before** saving and reopening:

[image: Before]

This is what the image looks like in GIMP **after** saving and reopening:

[image: After]

I notice that I can no longer see the alpha channel mask that is on the before version of the picture. I'm not sure if it has something to do with this message that I get when I try to save the before picture as a .bmp:

[image: Gimp]

Sorry that this is such a long post but I'm trying to give all the information I can. I'm not sure what my issue is in regards to the transparency on the MenuItem. I'm told that if you load a bitmap that has 32bpp and pre-multiplied alpha the transparency will work just fine.

I know that I cannot use the managed method `Bitmap.Gethbitmap()` because it loses the alpha channel. This is why I instead use `LoadImage` winapi call in the hopes of preserving it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am pretty sure this won't work since the MenuItem is drawn by GDI not GDI+ and GDI does not support image transparency.  Why aren't you using the ContextMenuStrip?

Comment: ContextMenu invokes ancient code inside Windows that dates back to the 1980s.  It renders menus with GDI which knows beans about transparency.  The only way ahead is to create your own 24bpp bitmap whose background matches the menu background color, use GetSysColor().

Comment: The system has supported alpha channel bitmaps in menu items since Vista (as long as themes are enabled), the OPs problem is loading the image and preserving the alpha channel.

Answer (score 8):

If you add the LR_CREATEDIBSECTION flag to the last argument of the LoadImage call, it will load the BMP resource as-is, including any alpha channel if it is a 32-bit BMP file. Doing anything else seems to lose the alpha channel (even if the desktop is set to 32bpp) as the image gets converted into a compatible bitmap.

Provided the BMP file itself is correct, that DIB then seems to work fine when assigned to a menu item using MIIM_BITMAP and hbmpItem.

This works with Vista through to Windows 8.1 when themes are enabled.

*This does not always work well when themes are disabled.* (Note that even in Windows 8, themes can be disabled by the application even if the user can no longer disable them system-wide.)

(Sometimes it also works OK with themes disabled and I honestly can't say why for sure. It works great on my main Win7x64 machine with and without themes, but in a test virtual machine also running Win7x64 it looks bad when themes are disabled. I suspect it depends on which other shell extensions have added things to the menu, and maybe if a 3rd party extension happens to uses an owner-draw icon it flips the shell into a different code-path which makes the new hbmpItem method also work by accident when it doesn't work by default if unthemed. That is just a guess, though. The inconsistency seems like a bug in Windows and one that is unlikely to be fixed given it's existed from Vista through to Windows 8.1 You just have to avoid using it when themes are disabled, even on Windows 7 or 8.)

*This does not work well on Windows XP*, whether themes are enabled or not.

On XP, and newer versions of Windows with themes disabled, the results can be ugly:

- The icon ends up too far to the right, in a different place to most other icons on the menu, and since the menu line height is smaller, a 16x16 icon which looks good and consistent with other icons in a themed menu will be too large in an unthemed menu.
- XP also ignores the alpha channel when provided a 32bpp HBITMAP, so you will get an icon with a solid black background.
- So, if you care about those cases, then you must fallback and either not provide the icon at all on older or unthemed systems, or provide an alternative icon. (Make it 13x13, and blend it with the system menu colour yourself at runtime.) You'll also want to use the hbmpUnchecked field instead of hbmpItem, so the icon displays in the desired place.
- Bonus: As if all this wasn't bad enough, the theme detection APIs are a mess and may tell you about the system-wide themes but not about whether or not the application has disabled themes in itself or been manifested to use the old comctl32.dll. This seems to be a good enough check, in addition to a test for Windows XP:

  `(IsThemeActive() && IsAppThemed() && (GetThemeAppProperties() & STAP_ALLOW_CONTROLS))`

  You might also want to use the [comctl32.dll DllGetVersion export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find out if the application is using comctl32.dll version 6 or above (which means themes are supported but won't tell you if they are enabled or disabled), but I am not sure if it is needed.

Back to the main case where themes are enabled and we're not on XP:

- If you see some transparency in the menu but have problems like strange dots and other artifacts, or the dots disappearing and the icon background turning white when you move the mouse over the menu item, it means the alpha channel isn't right. It needs to be premultiplied alpha, premultiplied with black.

I don't have GIMP installed so I can't help there, but here are the steps for creating the BMP file using Photoshop, in case they help someone.

In Photoshop:

- Take the source image as, say, a PNG.
- On the Channels tab, add a new layer (it should be called "Alpha" automatically).
- Fill the whole Alpha channel with black.
- Go back to the Layers tab and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-click the main layer (it should be the only layer so far) to select its transparency mask.
- Go back to the Channels tab and click the Alpha channel. The selection you made in the previous step should still be active; fill that selection with white.
- (At this point, you have a non-premultiplied alpha image with an explicit alpha channel.)
- Now go back to the Layers tab and a new layer behind the main one. Fill it with black.
- Finally, save the file as a 32-bpp BMP. (Make sure the Alpha Channels checkbox is ticked in Photoshop's Save As dialog.)

The combination of the alpha channel -- made before adding the background layer -- and the black background layer results in premultiplied alpha, premultiplied with black.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this approach is that `LoadImage()` doesn't support alpha either.

I think you should stick to loading the image with GDI+, since that does let you get at the alpha bits - you just need a manual method of getting those bits into a `HBITMAP` without losing them.

I don't know enough about .NET to categorically state that it doesn't support this, but I couldn't find a simple solution with a quick search. So I think your best bet is to to use [`Bitmap.LockBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to access the raw data, and then use [`CreateDIBSection()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) via [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/createdibsection.html?diff=y) and copy the bits into the DIB section yourself.

If both the source and destination bitmaps are the same size then it should just require a single `memcpy()` or equivalent to copy all the bitmap data at once (`x * y * 4` bytes).